# Why do two variables of the same type behave differently depending on how they were produced?

Tags: typescript

Why, given that both `nums` and `nums2` are of type `(0 | 1 | 2)[]`, do `tuple` and `tuple2` have different types?

```
// const nums: (0 | 1 | 2)[]
const nums: (0 | 1 | 2)[] = [];

// let tuple: (0 | 1 | 2)[]
let tuple = [nums[0], nums[1]];


// const nums2: (0 | 1 | 2)[]
const nums2 = ([] as {num?: 1 | 2}[]).
    map(n => typeof n.num === "undefined" ? 0 : n.num)

// let tuple2: number[]
let tuple2 = [nums2[0], nums2[1]];
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N91E8N)

Comment: I think you could minimalise the example down to [this](https://tsplay.dev/N91E8N)

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your question to use the [mre] from the previous comment, which shows the issue quite cleanly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of the difference between *widening* and *non-widening* [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#11126](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11126).  It's understandably confusing, because IntelliSense does not display these types any differently; it's an invisible attribute of the type.  For example, you can't tell if a type displayed as `0 | 1 | 2` is widening or not.

---

Generally speaking, a literal type that only occurs in an *expression* (and not in a *type*) will automatically widen to its corresponding base primitive type (so `0` will become `number`) when inferred in a place where the value could be reassigned (such as the element of a non-`readonly` array or tuple).  So for this:

```
const nums = ([] as { num?: 1 | 2 }[]).map(n => typeof n.num === "undefined" ? 0 : n.num)
// const nums: (0 | 1 | 2)[]
```

The type of `nums` is an array of *widening* literal types, because the type `0` comes from the expression `0` and the type `1 | 2` comes from the expression `n.num`, but nowhere in that `map()` method call are such types explicitly written as types.  And so `0 | 1 | 2` widens to `number` when inferred in a place that can be reassigned, such as an array literal:

```
let tuple = [nums[0], nums[1]];
// let tuple: number[]
```

---

On the other hand, a literal type that occurs explicitly in a *type* (not just an expression*) will *not* automatically widen in a similar situation.  So for this:

```
const nums: (0 | 1 | 2)[] = [];
// const nums: (0 | 1 | 2)[];
```

The type of `nums` is an array of *non-widening* literal types, because the type `0 | 1 | 2` comes from the *type annotation* for `nums`.  And so `0 | 1 | 2` does *not* widen to `number` when inferred in a place that can be reassigned, such as an array literal:

```
let tuple = [nums[0], nums[1]];
// let tuple: (0 | 1 | 2)[];
```

---

If you want a widening literal type to become non-widening, you can add an explicit type somewhere as a hint.  Like explicitly typing one of the values in the expression:

```
const nums = ([] as { num?: 1 | 2 }[]).map(n => typeof n.num === "undefined" ? 0 as 0 : n.num)
// const nums: (0 | 1 | 2)[]
let tuple = [nums[0], nums[1]];
// let tuple: (0 | 1 | 2)[];
```

or explicitly specifying the type parameter for the call to `map()`

```
const nums = ([] as { num?: 1 | 2 }[]).map<0 | 1 | 2>(n => typeof n.num === "undefined" ? 0 : n.num)
// const nums: (0 | 1 | 2)[]
let tuple = [nums[0], nums[1]];
// let tuple: (0 | 1 | 2)[];
```

or any of the methods discussed in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12267#issuecomment-260779573) inside [microsoft/TypeScript#12267](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12267).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCuBbCAuGAKADDAPjAjLjAEwCUA2gLowC8MVA3ALABQA9GzFzAHoD8rVgBsAprCjwADqNr0EycpkoAaOEgjl8lSs3adu-QS1CRY8iMVnoqMAIYQYAbzWI+aQnksBfKqQB0iLaS6GC0AHwwUACekiIgAGZwfvK0NHQARPBgACYi8QCWYCLZ6TB8MNhoYMlIpKwc3LwCLMJikVKilnTk5sSKKi4Wmtq6DQbNrCbQgwDMVjb2Ti5uBETevgFBIeGRMXGJ1SlpGVm5BUUlZRV2DpVJ8nV6jYYsouIdInPd5jP9qj-DHT1fRcF6TcDTcwAFnm1EWznkKw8JBgPko-kCkgAPNg8MjiGFtjQItFYgl7khUiccnlCsVSuU7odasDns03u1pCIYd91FC-oN+VogU9xkYgA)

Answer (score 1):

I think TypeScript reads:

```
let partOfSomeNums2 = [someNums2[1], someNums2[0]];
```

like

```
let partOfSomeNums2 = [0, 1];
```

In the second line: `partOfSomeNums2` is a `number[]`, just like the first line.

You can use:

```
let partOfSomeNums2 = [...someNums2.slice(1, 2), ...someNums2.slice(0, 1)];
```

Or:

```
let partOfSomeNums2: (0 | 1 | 2)[] = [someNums2[1], someNums2[0]];
```

I think your `someWorkingFunction` in your playground works because the type `0 | 1 | 2` is directly extracted from an enum, in contrary of your not working code, where the value `0` is hard coded.

**EDIT**

I would use this solution: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFgOrBgAWAShAM5hTC4QAmAcgK4C2605yA3gLABQyZCFYAuZAAZkAH2QBGacgBMAbn4BffggD2ISsnJaWEDNlzkxJnPkKkKVGpEat2UcgG0AusgC8yN-0EuIVEJZDUAGgDuYJYxeQiooOFYpTDIvg9VPn4wAE8ABxQAZRY4ABsy5jZoH1CZeRkVfn4YJhBcYB19Qwg8LSgAa1AAcwAxNo6dAAoASm4owW1dMG6jKs5fAyNLMwA6Uvypqa0sOe8APmQTzF3kmazBQTKIFfy4KDBUGCKe9dq3LYQdZuWQecKrIGsdziDyZBZ%20QHAmHgxFQkGw2pvD5fH5rKFZDTZPigSCwRAoHbWYhkSjUWhOaquVBQACqIDoEBgoHo8wEMQA-HEFE0%20ISlnpAZTyIoLFgrARqXY6Y4qi5yMy2RyuSB6J5-okEnykiF4ulAjExIo0vw4UTWu0wJ0QBCAEJQLQDCAgcYOp2zXmPZAAeiDyDyhSuMAh6ytwE4U0k9WFM08KLgRmQcE4qJY5Hh4pWOeltUlcrMin2cEOx1OYhK5UqzhqF3h4YgWij11urB83l8ACI2lruXR%208h%20aExF3kvD7vCQ8h0EwVsAowBJZAQAAeVEQr3eKw7yEI4OIKDbx84yTVnnhz332O%20vyhVt8AOfucU6JRH%20lbhhtqBguBibrswy7Jm%20gAO5VlchRQHAjpdHQWgUCAADkKxQf0AxoGWVK2LSDj0KqHDzqG-YACoFCg6HXtA6GXkIWgrFm5DAMMIBwOgzxhloYY0cg6GJnIwrobs-bwu%20eKfv%20YLRi%206JeL4WKfE%20MnSg8jwLhuCBwM6MD9Egx5YTYmbkOCS5YUQuTIChyAbkQcAAG7nlo-JSUWX7IgpsmgspyCqTiv5WlmyAJgoDRKCmtqEkAA)

Using this type: `type SmallNumber = 0 | 1 | 2;`
And then, use this type in your mapping function:

```
const someNums2 = someObjects2.map((obj): SmallNumber =>
    typeof obj.num === "undefined" ? 0 : obj.num
);
```

Comment: If that was the case, then [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nrn5aN) should be a `number[]` too. Yet it is not. Something else is going on here

Comment: Maybe because in your example you have explicitly written the type `0 | 1 | 2`. In the code that doesn't work, there is not such a typing: the return type is deducted by TS (I'm not sure, maybe I'm wrong)